# Stringstream buffer won't empty in Objective-C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I want to use std::stringstream in Objective-C++, but the buffer won't be empty after this line:

```
ss >> username >> name >> surname >> Id >> email;
```

My code looks like:

```
std::shared_ptr<Self> string_to_self(const std::string & info){
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.str(info);
    std::string username{""};
    std::string name{""};
    std::string surname{""};
    int Id{0};
    std::string email{""};

    ss >> username >> name >> surname >> Id >> email;

    //ss.str() is the same as 'info'.
```

Doesn't the stringstream works the same way in Objective-C++ as in C++ ? 
Is that any other alternative/better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a `std::istream_iterator` would be of more use to you here?

```
std::shared_ptr<Self> string_to_self(const std::string & info){
    std::stringstream ss(info);
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> foo(ss);
    const std::string username = *foo++;
    const std::string name = *foo++;
    const std::string surname = *foo++;
    const int Id = std::stoi(*foo++);
    const std::string email = *foo++;

    if(foo == std::istream_iterator<std::string>()){
        //empty
    }else{
        //not empty
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its working as expected, you should clear it yourself. You should call [`clear()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/) for cleaning any flags already set, then init it with a new value.

First method can avoid calling `const char` constructor of `std::string`

```
ss.clear();
ss.str(std::string());
```

or you can simply

```
ss.clear();
ss.str("");
```

which most of the modern compilers avoid call of `const char` constructor

Answer (score 0):

It's working as expected. The stringstream does not empty, it just adjusts the position of the manipulator.

so code like:

```
ss.str()
```

Returns a *copy* of content of the stringstream as a string (regardless of the offset that the read-pointer has within the string), and does not alter the content of the stringstream.

If you want to set the stream string to the remaining content, you need to do a little bit of a contrived:

```
ss.str(ss.tellg() == -1 ? "" : ss.str().substr(ss.tellg()));
```

This determines the seek position, and if it's `-1`, then blanks the content, otherwise sets it to the substring following the seek position.